# Perturbation to two-point correlation function for the anharmonic oscillator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, perturbation-theory, greens-functions, correlation-functions, anharmonic-oscillators

I am trying to answer a question regarding the computation of the first-order correction to the two-point correlation function for the anharmonic oscillator with Lagrangian:

$$ L = \frac{m}{2} \dot x^2 - \frac{m}{2} \omega^2 x^2 - \frac{\lambda}{4!} x^4 .$$

I need to compute the correction to first order in $\lambda$.
This correction goes via perturbation theory in which the unperturbed case is for $\lambda=0$ which has:

$$\langle x(t1)x(t2)\rangle_{\lambda=0} = i K_0^{-1}(t_1, t_2)$$

where we approximate $K_0^{-1}(t_1, t_2)$ by its $t_f - t_0 \rightarrow \infty $ expresion:

$$K_0^{-1}(t_1, t_2) = \frac{1}{2m\omega} e^{-i\omega|t_1-t_2|}.$$

I have and understand the following:
The lagrangian $L$ can be written as $L=L_0+L_1$ such that for the action also holds $S=S_0+S_1$, for which we then can factorize and approximate the exponential as $$e^{iS}=e^{iS_0}e^{iS_1}=e^{iS_0}(1+iS_1).$$ Which leads to the following:

$$\langle x(t_1)x(t_2)\rangle_{\lambda} = \frac{1}{Z}\int Dx(t) x(t_1)x(t_2) e^{iS_0}(1-\frac{i\lambda}{4!}\int_{t_1}^{t_2} x^4 dt)$$

Which then gives the unperturbed term plus some correction as:

$$\langle x(t_1)x(t_2)\rangle_{\lambda} = \langle x(t_1)x(t_2)\rangle_{\lambda=0} + correction.$$

Since the unperturbed is of course:
$$\langle x(t_1)x(t_2)\rangle_{\lambda=0}=\frac{1}{Z}\int Dx(t) x(t_1)x(t_2) e^{iS_0}. $$

This correction is then to my understanding the following:
$$ - \frac{i\lambda}{4!} \frac{1}{Z} \int Dx(t) x(t_1)x(t_2)\int_{t_1}^{t_2} x^4 dt.$$

I dont know whether this is correct and even if so I have trouble solving it. Could anyone help me into the right direction and/or confirm what I have already done.